# minimizing loss in tensorflow.js for feed forward neural network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow.js

I am trying to create a sample feed forward neural network in tensorflow.js using a small data set initially (just for POC). There are 5 input nodes and one output node. Data is related to housing where there are multiple inputs and we are predicting price.

```
x_train:
[ [ 79545.45857, 5.682861322, 7.009188143, 4.09, 23086.8005 ],
  [ 79248.64245, 6.002899808, 6.730821019, 3.09, 40173.07217 ],
  [ 61287.06718, 5.86588984, 8.51272743, 5.13, 36882.1594 ],
  [ 63345.24005, 7.188236095, 5.586728665, 3.26, 34310.24283 ],
  [ 59982.19723, 5.040554523, 7.839387785, 4.23, 26354.10947 ],
...
] 

y_train
[ [ 1059033.558 ],
  [ 1505890.915 ],
  [ 1058987.988 ],
  [ 1260616.807 ],
  [ 630943.4893 ],
...
]

const model = tf.sequential();
const config_hidden = {
        inputShape: [5],
        activation: 'sigmoid',
        units: 6
    }

const config_output = {
    units: 1,
    activation: 'sigmoid'
}

const hidden = tf.layers.dense(config_hidden);
const output = tf.layers.dense(config_output);

model.add(hidden);
model.add(output);

const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(0.5);

const config = {
    optimizer: optimizer,
    loss: 'meanSquaredError',
    metrics: ['accuracy']
}

model.compile(config);

train_data().then(function () {
    console.log('Training is Complete');
}

async function train_data() {
    const options = {
        shuffle: true,
        epochs: 10,
        batch_size: 100,
        validationSplit: 0.1
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const res = await model.fit(xs, ys, options);
        console.log(res.history.loss[0]);
    }
}
```

The model compiles fine. But the loss while training the model is huge

```
Model Successfully Compiled
Epoch 1 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
1058ms 235us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648912629760.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
Epoch 2 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
700ms 156us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648913285120.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
Epoch 3 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
615ms 137us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648913022976.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
Epoch 4 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
852ms 189us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648913285120.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
```

I figured it could be because the training data is not normalized. So I took the mean of the data and divided it

```
xs = xs.div(xs.mean(0));

x_train
[[1.1598413, 0.9507535, 1.003062 , 1.0272969, 0.6384002],
     [1.1555134, 1.0042965, 0.9632258, 0.7761241, 1.1108726],
     [0.8936182, 0.9813745, 1.2182286, 1.2885166, 1.0198718],
     ...,
```

There is not much change to the loss

```
Model Successfully Compiled
Epoch 1 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
841ms 187us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648912760832.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
Epoch 2 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
613ms 136us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648913154048.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
Epoch 3 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
646ms 144us/step - acc=0.00 loss=1648913022976.00 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=1586459705344.00
```

I then normalized the output too,

```
ys = ys.div(1000000);

Model Successfully Compiled
Epoch 1 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
899ms 200us/step - acc=0.00 loss=0.202 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=0.161
Epoch 2 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
667ms 148us/step - acc=0.00 loss=0.183 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=0.160
Epoch 3 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
609ms 135us/step - acc=0.00 loss=0.182 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=0.159
```

This brought the loss down to decimal figures. However it is seen that even running 10000 iterations on the training data does not decrease the loss substantially. e.g.

```
Epoch 8 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
502ms 112us/step - acc=0.00 loss=0.181 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=0.158
Epoch 9 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
551ms 122us/step - acc=0.00 loss=0.181 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=0.158
Epoch 10 / 10
eta=0.0 ====================================================================>
470ms 104us/step - acc=0.00 loss=0.181 val_acc=0.00 val_loss=0.158
0.18076679110527039
```

Finally the loss starts at around 0.202 and goes down to around 0.180. This results in incorrect predictions.

This is a very common scenario. Multiple inputs having values in different ranges (e.g. housing data as used above). Multiple inputs passed to a feed forward neural network. Expected only one output (price in this case).

Questions:
1. What am I doing wrong in the code above?
2. Am I normalizing the data in the correct manner?
3. Am I using the correct loss function/optimizer/learning rate/activation etc.
4. How do I know whether the model is performing good
5. Is there any other way to do this in tensorflow.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your not attempting linear regression, because of the sigmoidal activations. If you are trying linear regression, remove the sigmoidal activations everywhere. Will try and address all the errors I can see:

1. Remove the sigmoid activation from the output. The sigmoid function squashes inputs to between 0 and 1, so it's not meant for regression. Your last layer does not need an activation.
2. Your learning rate is way too high, so I doubt a learning algorithm would be able to converge. Start off with values around 0.001 - 0.01 etc and adjust if required.
3. No your not normalizing correctly. Generally data is normalised to a mean of zero and standard deviation of one. This is done for each feature column, using the mean and standard deviation of that column only, not all of the data. The formula for example `i` in feature column `x` is as follows: `(x_i - x.mean()) / x.std()`. (I don't know javascript)
4. The performance metric you provided, "accuracy", is meant for classification, not regression, and would be meaningless (if it is even provided). Minimising your mean squared error or absolute square error is the best way to quantify model performance.

Comment: I removed "sigmoid" from the output layer and set the learning rate to 0.1 to begin with. There is definite improvement in the loss which is now in the range of 0.01 and decreasing. I used "relu" activation for the hidden layer. Hope that's fine. For the metrics, I used 'mse'. I also want to get the percentage accuracy of the model. How do I get that? Regarding the normalization, I understand what you are saying, but I couldn't find the std() function in tensorflow.js. One suggestion was to use ((x_i - min)/(max-min)).

Comment: Using relu in the hidden layer is fine, just note that you are now not implementing linear regression, but increased the capacity of your model to search for nonlinear correlations. Just by looking at the tensorflow docs, theres a metric "meanAbsolutePercentageError", which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: The normalisation method you mentioned is just another variant of the process, and also fine to use. Just make sure you are normalising each feature (column) separately.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I am trying to predict housing prices from 5 features in the input data. So regression is probably what I want (I may be wrong). Should I just remove the activation function from all layers?

Comment: Tensorflow.js seems use accuracy: ['mse']. Taking a cue I used ['mape'] for meanAbsolutePercentageError though it didn't list it explicitly in the documentation as such. I get the output as { val_loss: [ 0.007765776012092829 ],
  val_mape: [ 17.398786544799805 ],
  loss: [ 0.008923463523387909 ],
  mape: [ 41699.80859375 ] }. the value of mape seems to be way off

Comment: That is indeed regression. Whether you use no activations (linear) or relu (nonlinear) depends on your data. Try both and see which one works the best. The real way to see performance is to test your trained model on a test set (a portion of original data that was not used to train the model) and see whether the predictions on that dataset is close to the real prices.

Comment: I would highly recommend a basic tutorial on machine learning first before attempting this again. Just so you are more aware of what you're doing. Neural networks are more advanced topics, and you should first obtain a better understanding of the basics. Andrew Ng's machine learning course on coursera is a great start

Comment: I have completed Andrew's machine learning course which did give me the basics. Problem is tensorflow is more high level and I don't find proper documentation on the usage of various parameters and their implications. I am still learning. Thanks for your time

Comment: There are a lot more Tensorflow for python material and tutorials for problems similar to yours online. I would recommend searching through these in the future, the API is very much the same and I'm sure will be helpful. Python is also a very readable language, so should easily make sense with no python skills. All good, good luck